# Can't find model in CodeIgniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I load the `Get_notes` model in line 8, but when I want to use `Get_notes` model to load `add_notes` method in line 23, the error occur and say `Undefined property: Notes::$Get_notes` in line 23 !
There is something wrong in line 23 but I dont know what is that.Please help me.
Thanks

```
<?php

class Notes extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Get_notes');
        $data['notes'] = $this->Get_notes->get_mm();
        $this->load->view('show', $data);
    }

    public function insert()
    {
        $title = 'Something';
        $text = 'Something else';

        $data = [
            'title' => $title,
            'text' => $text
        ];

        $this->Get_notes->add_notes($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, you need to make some changes like `$this->load->model('Get_notes');` to `$this->load->model('get_notes');` and `$this->Get_notes->get_mm();` to `$this->get_notes->get_mm();`. The problem may be capitalized in the call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you've written it, your `Get_notes` Model is only available within your `index()` function.

---

To make your `Get_notes` Model available to all functions within a single Controller, load it within that [Controller's constructor function](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors)...

```
class Notes extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('get_notes'); // available to all functions within Notes 
    }
    ....
```

---

To make your `Get_notes` Model available globally to all functions in any CI Controller, put it in your `$autoload['model']` array within the `autoload.php` file located at `application/config/autoload.php`...

```
$autoload['model'] = array('get_notes'); // available to all functions in your CI application
```

---

→ Note that it's supposed to be written in **all lower-case** no matter how you reference it later.

```
$this->load->model('get_notes');
$this->get_notes->add_notes($data);
```

---

See:

- [Class Constructors](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#class-constructors)

> If you intend to use a constructor in any of your Controllers, you MUST place the following line of code in it:
>
> `parent::__construct(); // Notice there is no dollar sign`

- [Anatomy of a Model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model):

> Where `Model_name` is the name of your class. Class names **must have the first letter capitalized** with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.

- [Loading a Model](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model):

> Your models will typically be loaded and called from within your controller methods. To load a model you will use the following method:
>
> `$this->load->model('model_name');`
>
> Once loaded, you will access your model methods using an object with the same name as your class:
>
> `$this->model_name->method();`

- [Auto-loading Resources](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/autoloader.html#auto-loading-resources)

> To autoload resources, open the `application/config/autoload.php` file and add the item you want loaded to the autoload array. You’ll find instructions in that file corresponding to each type of item.

Answer (score 0):

An codeigniter model call is case sensitive therefore to get an model you should use

```
$this->get_notes->a_function_inside_the_model ();
```

Also note that the name inside the model folder should always start with a uppercase.

Whenever we run codeigniter on localhost servers like wamp server these problems dont exist but on a live server they will.

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score -1):

Your get_notes model is only loaded in the index function. You cannot load the model in the index function and use it in any other function without having to load it again.
I'm thinking you're trying to load the model once and use it throughout your controller. To do this, you have to load it in the __construct method instead. Your code should be similar to this:

```
<?php

class Notes extends CI_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Get_notes');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        $data['notes'] = $this->Get_notes->get_mm();
        $this->load->view('show', $data);
    }

    public function insert()
    {
        $title = 'Something';
        $text = 'Something else';

        $data = [
            'title' => $title,
            'text' => $text
        ];

        $this->Get_notes->add_notes($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put $this->load->model('Get_notes'); in the insert() function.

If you want to use it globally, put it in a constructor.